# Django and APScheduler not running on IIS Server

Tags: django, iis, apscheduler

We have a django app which we deployed using **IIS Server**. The app has been running smoothly and without any problem. However, we want to **schedule** a job that will run every night at 02:00.
We are using **APScheduler** which is working perfectly fine on the django local server but it never runs on production.
Here is the code I am using to run the jobs.

**myapp/scheduler.py**

```
def schedule():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(daily_schedules, 'interval', minutes=5)
    # scheduler.add_job(daily_schedules, trigger='cron', hour='2')
    scheduler.start()


def daily_schedules():
    time_now = time.clock()
    parse_api() # my function
    # Keeping logs
    path = join(settings.FILES_DIR, 'schedulled/logs.csv')
    logs = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
    time_end = time.clock() - time_now
    logs.loc[len(logs)] = [
        datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), time_end
        ]
    logs.to_csv(path, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    print(logs)
```

**myapp/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'MyApp'

    def ready(self):
        from myapp import scheduler
        scheduler.schedule()
```

Is there any particular reason why the job is not being run? Do I need to do something else or this method does not work with IIS? Since the server is being used by many developers at the same time, I would like to run the jobs as part of the django application and not run them outside in a separate server.

P.S: I have read all the stackoverflow questions on this matter but none seem to answer my questions.

Comment: You can write the schedule to a task and then execute the task.

Comment: Isn't there a way to schedule the tasks using Django? I would like the scheduling to be part of the app because I want the application to be independent of me (if I am not in the company).